# Working on different editions of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a quick question about SQL Server, let's say I'm using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise, I created a database adding tables, stored procedures, functions, etc.

Then, after a while I decided to restore that database on a SQL Server 2014 Developer edition, is there any limitation or issue I should consider? Or is transparent since is the same version?

Comment: It is fine. And as per the developer version, it is equal to enterprise edition (only not to be used for anything other than development). You can restore it to 2014 and later.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the restore will work. You can restore to an equal edition and up, but you can't restore down a version. However, Enterprise/Standard/Dev have different capabilities available, so all the functionality might not work.

Here is a list of the editions and their capabilities.: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Developer edition has all of the features enabled, so you can restore backups from any other edition of SQL Server.  You can restore backups made by older versions, but not newer.

Enterprise does have some features not found in Standard or Express, so those will not necessarily work.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2016 SP1, we did some work to make the surface area more similar across the SKUs.  In other words, we made previously Enterprise Edition-only features available in lower SKUs.  For example, we exposed Columnstore and batch mode processing in Standard edition.  The intent is to make it easier for ISVs to program to the latest feature set instead of targeting the lowest-common denominator.  Note that advanced features will usually perform better/scale better in Enterprise edition, so there are still non-functional differences in the SKUs.

Here is a posting summarizing the changes that were made:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/

Hope that helps,
Conor